# Is there any method to inject browser JS in apostrophe-pages?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm interested into a method like `self.play` from apostrophe-widgets that permit us apply Jquery selectors without having any doubt that the selector only should be applied to the widget, thanks to `$widget` parameter.

What I want to obtain is the same behaviour but with apostrophe-pages, I've research into the documentation and I didn't find anything. Is there any way to replicate the same behaviour?

I let a reference to the method I'm talking about to clarify the question.
https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/modules/apostrophe-widgets#more

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no equivalent `player` for pages. Typically we push those front-end modules all the time and let them decide when they're relevant or not. Because there is no equivalent, there is no concept of a safe jQuery `$widget` object or `data` about the page being passed down.

That pattern around pushing page-specific modules is illustrated in the Open Museum demo in the `apostrophe-assets` module.

https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-open-museum/tree/master/lib/modules/apostrophe-assets

A widget's `player` method is really nice because it knows to re-run itself when Apostrophe does various editing/saving operations. You can get similar re-running behavior anywhere by listening for the front-end `apos` event `ready`. A bit of documentation on that here https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/tutorials/howtos/migration#browser-side-javascript-is-pretty-close-to-the-same